# Python: extract a list that appears in a specific row of an HTML table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code to get the small table on the right hand side of Apple's wikipedia page (the one that contains basic information about the company):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

WIKI_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc."

req = requests.get(WIKI_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')
table_classes = {"class": ["infobox vcard"]}
wikitables = soup.find("table", table_classes)
```

I would like to add some extra lines of code to extract the itemized list in the row of the table with th **Products**. In other words, I would like to create a list that will look like this

```
 ['Macintosh',
 'iPod',
 'iPhone',
 'iPad',
 'Apple Watch',
 'Apple TV',
 'HomePod',
 'macOS',
 'iOS',
 'watchOS',
 'tvOS',
 'iLife']
```

I would like to write this as part of a code in such a way that I will be able to use the code to extract similar information from the Wiki page of other companies. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you read the bs4 docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scrape all the data from the wikipedia info box, clean each string by removing all extraneous spaces and new line characters, and then group to find each header row and corresponding list of values:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib
import re
import itertools
s = soup(str(urllib.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.').read()), 'lxml')
rows = map(lambda x:re.sub('\s+', ' ', x.text), s.find_all('th', {'scope':'row'}))
info_box = [re.split('\n+', i.text) for i in s.find_all('table', {'class':'infobox vcard'})][0]
final_data = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(info_box, key=lambda x:x in rows)]
products = [a for i, a in enumerate(final_data) if final_data[i-1][0] == u'Products'][0]
```

Output:

```
[u'Macintosh', u'iPod', u'iPhone', u'iPad', u'Apple Watch', u'Apple TV', u'HomePod', u'macOS', u'iOS', u'watchOS', u'tvOS', u'iLife', u'iWork']
```

Edit: For Python3.x, this solution uses the more robust `requests` module instead of `urllib`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import re
import itertools
s = soup(str(requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.').text), 'html.parser')
rows = list(map(lambda x:re.sub('\s+', ' ', x.text), s.find_all('th', {'scope':'row'})))
info_box = [re.split('\n+', i.text) for i in s.find_all('table', {'class':'infobox vcard'})][0]
final_data = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(info_box, key=lambda x:x in rows)]
products = [a for i, a in enumerate(final_data) if final_data[i-1][0] == u'Products'][0]
```

Output:

```
['Macintosh', 'iPod', 'iPhone', 'iPad', 'Apple Watch', 'Apple TV', 'HomePod', 'macOS', 'iOS', 'watchOS', 'tvOS', 'iLife', 'iWork']
```

Comment: Thanks. I should probably mention that I am using Python 3.6.3. When I try to run your proposed code as is, I get the error message `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'`. I then modified the fifth line of your code to `s = soup(str(urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.').read()), 'lxml')`. Unfortunately, I now get the message `IndexError: list index out of range` in the last line of the code. Any thoughts on how to fix this?